# How to prevent deep indentations?

Tags: code-quality, indentation

What steps and measures can I take to prevent deep indentations in my code?

Comment: A lot of people will talk about refactoring here. Maybe this is too much to ask, but if you posted some (not too long) code that is deeply indented, and people could show you how they'd refactor it. Of course, that probably makes the question language specific then...

Comment: Use a smaller tab width.

Comment: **Arrowhead** anti-pattern. Google it, loads of tips

Comment: Stop using python :D

Comment: It's time to look at your control and loop logic. Likely your code is more complicated than it needs to be, and a re-conceptualization of the problem will lead to much shorter code. Study good code and learn the techniques.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Deep indentation is *usually* not a problem if every function/method in your program does one and only one thing. Occasionally, it *might* be necessary to nest conditionals a few levels deep, but I can honestly say I've only written deeply indented code a handful of times in 12+ years of coding.

Answer (score 28):

The best thing you can do is extract methods:

```
int Step1(int state)
{
    if (state == 100)
    {
        return Step2(state);
    }
    else
    {
        return Step3(state);
    }
}

int Step2(int state)
{
    if (state != 100)
    {
        throw new InvalidStateException(2, state);
    }

    // ....
}
```

Comment: This also works for complex `if`-conditions. Taken to the extreme, you'll end up with executable pseudocode.

Comment: Other best thing we can do is to probably drop unnecessary `else` blocks.

Answer (score 18):

Maybe you could consider **guard clauses**?

instead of

```
public void DoSomething(int value){
    if (someCondition){
           if(someOtherCondition){
                if(yetAnotherCondition){
                       //Finally execute some code
                }
           }
    }
}
```

Do

```
public void DoSomething(int value){
    if(!(someCondition && someOtherCondition && yetAnotherCondition)){
        return;
        //Maybe throw exception if all preconditions must be true
    }
    //All preconditions are safe execute code
}
```

If you ever get a chance I'd reccommend you read Code Complete by Steve McConnell. He's got a lot of great advise on these topics.

[http://www.amazon.com/Code-Complete-Practical-Handbook-Construction/dp/0735619670/ref=pd_sim_b_6](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0735619670)

For more about "guard clauses" see: https://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-nested-conditional-with-guard-clauses

Answer (score 8):

**Invert your `if`s.**

Instead of:

```
if (foo != null)
{
    something;
    something;
    if (x)
    {        
       something;
    }
    something;
}
else
{
    boohoo;
}
```

I'd write:

```
if (foo == null)
{
    boohoo;
    return;
}
something;
something;
if (x)
{        
   something;
}
something;
```

The same applies to `if`-`else` blocks. If `else` is shorter / less nested, then revert them.

**Check parameters' values in one place**

Check all the parameters for illegal values as soon as you enter your method, then proceed knowing that you're safe. It makes for more readable code, but it also saves you piling up conditional blocks later on and spreading these checks all over the subroutine.

Comment: Does this style has a specific name?

Comment: @ThomasLauria not that I'd know of. It's just exiting early. `If`s at the beginning of code which stop the execution flow due to some condition not being met are also known as *safeguard clauses*, like @JasonTuran pointed out. And that seems to be as close as it gets to having a distinct name.

Comment: some years ago my supervisor told me that this style was named as "linear programming", but I think this was a phantasm of him ;)

Answer (score 4):

Typically, I have seen that deeply indented code is usually problematic code. If you are facing this problem, then step back and evaluate if your function is doing too many things.

At the same time, to answer your question, if there is a need for indentation that deep, I would suggest that you let it be there. For the simple reason that in such code, the indentation will help since it is likely to be a very long piece of code.

Answer (score 2):

Break nested components (especially repeated ones) out into separate functions (this is easier if your language supports closures) or replace a series of nested loops with a recursion.

Also, indent two spaces instead of four.

Comment: Once you've gone to the step of changing your tab width, you're in deep trouble...

Comment: Two-space tabs are the hard stuff....

Comment: Changing the indent is just a way of hiding the problem not a solution

Answer (score 1):

I don't see deep indentations as a categorical problem to be removed (nor do I see refactoring as the true answer for everything).

Typically instead of nested ifs, I like to write logical statements:

```
if (foo && bar && baz)
```

rather than

```
if foo 
 if bar
   if baz
```

Comment: The problem is, there do also exist for and while loops that don't fall under this rule.

Comment: @TomWij: I am not trying to induce a categorical imperative about style.

Comment: ???
` `
` `
` `

Answer (score 1):

I didn't believe it myself, but according to Code Complete this is an appropriate place to use `break` (if your team is on board).  I'd imagine this is more acceptable with C++ programmers though, where `break` used in `switch` statements than it is with Delphi programmers where `break` is only used when you don't feel like writing a `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Indentation is really a think to fight, indeed.
What I learned to do is to divide the method into pieces first, then use a weird trick to skip every following pieces if one piece failed.
Here is an example :

Instead of :

```
 {if (networkCardIsOn() == true)
     {if (PingToServer() == true)
        {if (AccesLogin(login,pass) == true)
             {if (nextCondition == true)
                ...
         }
     }
 }
```

I currently write :

```
 {vbContinue = true;

 if (vbContinue) {
       vbContinue = networkCardIsOn();
       if (vbContinue == false) {
             code to Handle This Error();
       } 
 }

 if (vbContinue) {
       vbContinue = PingToServer();
       if (vbContinue == false) {
             code to HandleThisError2();
       } 
 }

 if (vbContinue) {
       vbContinue = AccesLogin(login,pass);
      if (vbContinue == false) {
             HandleThisErrorToo();
       } 
 }
 ...
```

This has seem strange to me at a first, but since I use this, the maintenance cost has been divided by half, and my brain is cooler at the end of the day.

In fact, the gain introduced by this "technique" is that the code complexity is really divided because the code is less dense.

While reading the code, you don't have to remember anything about the past conditions : if your are at that point X in the code, the previous steps are passed and have succeeded.

Another gain is that "escape path and condition" from all those nested "if-else" is simplified.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "the maintenance cost has been divided by half" Also, how would you really know which if halted execution ?

Comment: I've done some editing. I hope I answer your questions...

Comment: If you want to go even simply, you have a goto error_handling line.

Comment: That's not nice. Sorry, but its just not. Then again I'm weird

Comment: @Murph. It's not about to be nice. It's about to be simple, dead easy to maintain. I know that 'look' strange, but it isn't. It's a way the split the complexity by making small individual steps.

Comment: Yes but that's my point I don't think you've made it less complex. But I'm weird.

Comment: instead of emulating a try catch why not use one directly ?

Comment: I don't like this code. It looks overbloated with low-level conditional checks.

Comment: @Newtopian: One reason is because exception-handling constructs can *implicitly* create many possible control flows, most of which are near-invisible to the casual eye.  This invites hard-to-find and hard-to-test bugs.  (For example, it's famously difficult to write exception-safe C++.)  Explicit control flow simultaneously limits, and makes clearly visible, the set of possible control flows.